Directly linking to Github Codespaces for public code example files
We have some Jupyter Notebooks we use for code examples, hosted in a public Github repository.

Currently we generate links which automatically open the notebook inside Google Colab and Binder cloud code editing environments, so the user can directly run the notebook using their web browser
However we'd like to do the linking using Github Codespaces instead, as it offers better editing experience, custom Docker image and is still free (we do not need to pay for our users, but they can pay themselves)

Does Github Codespaces offer a feature that you directly link to a file in a Github repository, and then it opens this file in Codespaces Dev Container?
